# Hackathon: Converting json to SRT format in React, and getting the video to read the SRT

Tags: json, reactjs, video, srt

Currently have a react app for a project at our hackathon. Due in 1 hour and here is our issue.

So we have this video player that will read a custom subtitle in SRT format. I have stored the user input into JSON and coverted it to SRT format, however, we want the video to read the SRT variable, since we can't read and write a file in React.

Code is here: https://github.com/Boka44/Subdub

This component takes the input and stores it into JSON, then converts to SRT format.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Caption extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            srt: [
            {
               number: "1",
               start: '00:00:00,750',
               end:'00:00:04,750',
               text: "Your predilections for the bottle are tearing this family apart!"
           },
           {
               number: "2",
               start: '00:00:05,000',
               end: '00:00:06,000',
               text: "*giggle*"
           },
           {
               number: "3",
               start: '00:00:06,750',
               end: '00:00:10,750',
               text: "This is serious business Leopold!"
           },
           {
               number: "4",
               start: '00:00:11,000',
               end: '00:00:13,000',
               text: "You don't know what you're talking about..."
           },
           {
               number: "5",
               start: '00:00:13,000',
               end: '00:00:17,000',
               text: "Blah blah blah, you're in denial Leo!"
           },
           {
               number: "6",
               start: '00:00:17,500',
               end: '00:00:21,000',
               text: "I know what denial looks like!"
           },
           {
               number: "7",
               start: '00:00:21,500',
               end: '00:00:24,000',
               text: "You're too much sometimes."
           },
           {
               number: "8",
               start: '00:00:24,500',
               end: '00:00:25,500',
               text: "*giggle*"
           },
           {
               number: "9",
               start: '00:00:26,500',
               end: '000:00:27,500',
               text: "*tee hee*"
           },
           {
               number: "10",
               start: '00:00:27,750',
               end: '00:00:30,000',
               text: "Well will you at least share the bottle?"
           },
           {
               number: "11",
               start: '00:00:30,500',
               end: '00:00:32,500',
               text: "No! The milk is all mine!"
           },
           {
               number: "12",
               start: '00:00:32,500',
               end: '00:00:35,000',
               text: "But I'm famished Leo!"
           },
           {
               number: "13",
               start: '00:00:36,000',
               end: '00:00:37,000',
               text: "*heeheehee*"
           },
           {
               number: "14",
               start: '00:00:42,000',
               end: '00:00:45,000',
               text: "Just messing."
           }
            ]
        }

    }
    onChange = (number, e) => {
        let store = e.target.value;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            srt: prevState.srt.map(caption => ({
                ...caption,
                text: caption.number === number ? store : caption.text
            }))
        }))

    }

    onClick = () => {

        let srtString = this.state.srt.map((caption, index) => {
            return (index > 0 ? '\n' : '') + [
              caption.number,
              `${caption.start} --> ${(caption.end)}`,
              caption.text
            ].join('\n')
          }).join('\n') + '\n';


        this.props.onSubmit(srtString)
        console.log(srtString)

    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                Enter captions:
                {this.state.srt.map(caption => 
                    <div key={caption.number}>
                        {caption.number}
                        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <input placeholder="Enter texthere" value={caption.text} onChange={(e) => this.onChange(caption.number, e)} />

                        </form>
                    </div>
                )}
                <button onClick={this.onClick} >add</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

This is the idea for the video:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TalkingTwins from '../video/TalkingTwins.mp4'

export class Video extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            srt: undefined,
            bool: false
        }
    }

    // componentDidMount(){
    //  this.setState({
    //      srt: this.props.srt
    //  })
    //  console.log('updated first time')
    // }


    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
            this.setState({
                srt: this.props.srtString,
                bool: true
            })
            console.log(this.state.srt)     
    }



    render() {
        return(
            this.state.bool ? (
            <div>   
            <video controls="controls" width="320" height="176">
                <source src={TalkingTwins} type="video/mp4" />
                <track src={this.state.srt} kind="subtitle" srclang="en-US" label="English" />
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
            </div>) : 
            (<video controls="controls" width="320" height="176">
                <source src={TalkingTwins} type="video/mp4" />
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>)
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Did I come too late?  Is the hackathon over?  How did it go?

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/gnuns/srtToJSON